# Regular Expression to select first five CSVs from a string

Tags: java, regex

I have a CSV string like `apple404, orange pie, wind\,cool, sun\\mooon, earth,` in Java. To be precise each value of the csv string could be any thing provided commas and backslash are escaped using a back slash.

I need a regular expression to find the first five values. After  some goggling I came up with the following. But it wont allow escaped commas within the values.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^,]+,){0,5}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("apple404, orange pie, wind\\,cool, sun\\\\mooon, earth,");
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    } else {
        System.out.println("No match found.");
    }
```

Does anybody know how to make it work for escaped commas within values?

Comment: So what's the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following negative look-behind based regex will work:

```
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:.*?(?<!(?:(?<!\\\\)\\\\)),){0,5}");
```

However for full fledged CSV parsing better use a dedicated CSV parser like [JavaCSV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacsv/).

Comment: Just because a comma is preceded by a backslash does not mean the backslash itself is actually a literal backslash. The existence of a backslash as an escaping character means the backslash itself could be escaped. It is a principle of encoding that any reading method that does not deal with escaped escaping characters does not in fact deal with any other escaped character either.

Comment: For the record, this "accepted" answer is wrong unless it can properly parse the example input that I provided already in my answer. Currently it fails to separate the fields `"sun\\,mooon".` (Since this discussion is over for now, I'm not going to take the time to write full Java code for my answer, but will just leave in in JavaScript R.E. form for the curious readers who may come later.)

Comment: @JosephMyers: Hope you understand that Javascript != Java, rest you will understand when you actually translate your Javascript code into Java :P

Comment: Yes, I do respectfully understand that.

Comment: If my reg-exp doesn't work for you, it is only because you are not properly escaping the backslash characters when putting inside of `Pattern.compile`. Which is actually a good example of the point I am trying to make.

Comment: no, this doesn't work with the following input: `",,apple404, orange pie, wind\\" + ",cool, sun\\mooon,"`.

Comment: As I said it is better to use proper CSV parser for very complex CSV parsing.

Comment: @Dru: I tested my answer with your input: `",,apple404, orange pie, wind\\" + ",cool, sun\\mooon,"` and got this output: `",,apple404, orange pie, wind\,cool,"` which is CORRECT.

Comment: "To a man with a hammer, everything looks like a nail." You are like the "man with a hammer," fixated on the simplistic idea of a negative look-behind, when in fact that does not meet the OP's requirements: *"To be precise each value of the csv string could be any thing [sic] provided commas **and backslash** are escaped using a back slash."* Your answer does not deal with escaped backslashes. Hence, it is wrong. I am disappointed to come back today and see you still have not fixed your answer even though you knew what was wrong with it. You have an obligation to the community to do better.

Comment: @JosephMyers: I guess you need to prove your case first before writing your blog articles in comments section here. I never claimed to solve all CSV problems using regex and that's why recommended use of CSV parser.

Comment: Your code treats `field1\\,field2,` as one field rather than two. If you have six of those fields, your solution will treat it as only three fields and match more than the OP desired. Do you understand now? BTW, the OP didn't ask us to solve all CSV problems, just the precise issues that he described: "To be precise each value of the csv string could be any thing [sic] provided commas and backslash are escaped using a back slash."

Comment: I think its better to let it be decided by OP what works out best for him/her.

Comment: @JosephMyers: I have edited my answer to suit your sample string however I still believe that its better/safer to use a dedicated CSV parser for full fledged parsing.

Comment: Your updated answer works only on double-backslash sequences, but not on triple (or higher) backslash sequences: `f\,ield1,field2\\,field3\\\,more of field3\\,field4\\,field5\\,field6\\,field7\\,field8\\,field9` Your code matches `f\,ield1,field2\\,field3\\\,more of field3\\,field4\\,` but my code matches `f\,ield1,field2\\,field3\\\,more of field3\\,field4\\,field5\\,`

Comment: I have tested above code with even: `String s = "apple\\\\\\\\,404, orange pie, wind\\,cool, sun\\\\mooon, earth,";` and it has worked.

Comment: Your code still fails on any comma preceded by an unescaped backslash and also preceded by one or more escaped backslashes (i.e., 3, 5, 7, ... total backslashes / 6, 10, 14, ... total backslashes in a Java string literal representation). My comment shows this case (your Java string literal does not show this case). **I agree completely with you that it is better to use a CSV parser for full-fledged parsing. So that part of your answer is correct.**

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression works well. It also properly recognizes not only backslash-escaped commas, but also backslash-escaped backslashes. Also, the matches it produces do not contain the commas.

```
/(?:\\\\|\\,|[^,])*/g
```

(I am using standard regular expression notation with the understanding that you would replace the delimiters with quote marks and double all backslashes when representing this regular expression within a Java string literal.)

example input

> "apple404, orange pie, wind\,cool, sun\\,mooon, earth"

produces this output

1. "apple404"
2. " orange pie"
3. " wind\,cool"
4. " sun\\"
5. "mooon"

Note that the double backslash after "sun" is escaped and therefore does not escape the following comma.

The way this regular expression works is by atomizing the input into longest sequences first, beginning with double backslashes (treating them as one possible multi-byte character value alternative), followed by escaped commas (a second possible multi-byte character alternative), followed by any non-comma value. Any number of these atoms are matched, followed by a literal comma.

In order to obtain the first N fields, one may simply splice the array of matches from the previous answer or surround the main expression in additional parentheses, include an optional comma in order to match the contents between fields, anchor it to the beginning of the string to prevent the engine from returning further groups of N fields, and quantify it (with N = 5 here):

```
/^((?:\\\\|\\,|[^,])*,?){0,5}/g
```

Once again, I am using standard regular expression notation, but here I will also do the trivial exercise of quoting this as a Java string:

```
"^((?:\\\\\\\\|\\\\,|[^,])*,?){0,5}"
```

This is the only solution on this page so far which actually answers both parts of the precise requirements specified by the OP, *"...commas and backslash are escaped using a back slash*." For the input `fi\,eld1\\,field2\\,field3\\,field4\\,field5\\,field6\\,`, it properly matches only the first five fields `fi\,eld1\\,field2\\,field3\\,field4\\,field5\\,`.

*Note*: my first answer made the same assumption that is implicitly part of the OP's original code and example data, which required a comma to be following every field. The problem was that if input is exactly 5 fields or less, and the last field not followed by a comma (equivalently, by an empty field), then final field would not be matched. I did not like this, and so I updated both of my answers so that they do not require following commas.

The shortcoming with this answer is that it follows the OP's assumption that values between commas contain "anything" plus escaped commas or escaped backslashes (i.e., no distinction between strings in double quotes, etc., but only recognition of escaped commas and backslashes). My answer fulfills the criteria of that imaginary scenario. But in the real world, someone would expect to be able to use double quotes around a CSV field in order to include commas within a field without using backslashes.

So I echo the words of @anubhava and suggest that a "real" CSV parser should always be used when handling CSV data. Doing otherwise is just being a script kiddie and not in any way truly "handling" CSV data.

[image: Java evaluation results]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.split()` here. By specifying the `limit` as `6` the first five elements (index `0` to `4`) would always be the first five column values from your CSV string. **If** in case any extra column values are present they would all overflow to index `5`.

The regex `(?<!\\\\),` makes sure the CSV string is only split at a `,` comma not preceded with a `\`.

```
String[] cols = "apple404, orange pie, wind\\,cool, sun\\\\mooon, earth, " +
                "mars, venus, pluto".split("(?<!\\\\),", 6);

System.out.println(cols.length); // 6
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cols));
// [apple404,  orange pie,  wind\,cool,  sun\\mooon,  earth,  mars, venus, pluto]

System.out.println(cols[4]); // 5th = earth 
System.out.println(cols[5]); // 6th discarded = mars, venus, pluto
```

Comment: +1 yes negative lookbehind is the way to go for this problem.